# Partition graph in a way that minimizes inter-partition edges

Tags: graphs, partitions

I have a graph in which certain vertices are labeled. I need to assign labels to all of the other vertices in a way that minimizes the number of edges between different-label vertices.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Hi Zach could you provide a bit more context? e.g. in how many groups do you want to partition your graph? (notice that if you partition your graph into one group there are zero inter-partition edges) And if the number of partitions is constant or not is also of relevance.

Comment: @plshelp Any number of partitions. But as I describe in my question, certain vertices are already assigned a partition, and those can't be changed.

Comment: Such has been call [min-cut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut).